# I need to display a toast in react according to the type received but its does not display in react

Tags: reactjs

here is my code in the component Error that I try to call in the component home.js but its not displayed

```
import { useToasts } from "react-toast-notifications";
import React from "react";
const Error = ( type) => {
    const { addToast } = useToasts();

    switch (type) {
        case "success":
            return  addToast('Saved Successfully', { appearance: 'success' })
        default:
            return (
                <div>
                    <p>default</p>
                </div>
            )
    }
};


export default Error;
```

and in my component I call

```
Error('success')
```

but nothing is displayed

Answer (score 1):

`addToast` most likely is an action, not a displayable content. Therefore you need to wire it with an event handler.

```
  <button OnClick={ () => { addToast(...) } }>Add<button>
```

In order to display it, look for other properties, ex.  `{ items } = useToast`, sorry i'm not familiar with the toast.

Answer (score 0):

is Error a function/hook or component? If it suppose to be component, then you need to pass type as property of props object so `Error = ({type}) =>`

then you put your Error component inside other component in render method as `<Error type='success' />`

Comment: how I will go about posting it in the catch blog of useeffect after error requests from the backen

Comment: I would need to see your usge of error function

Comment: also have you wrapped your whole app with `<ToastProvider>`?

Comment: I want to trigger the toast automatically if the function is successful or not
const fetchUser = async () => {
try {
Error('success')
}
catch((err) => {
      Error('erreur')
    });

}